# FireBase API Auth failure

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have setup firebase user authentication for an android studio project. After testing some, I eventually got the below error

API: InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device.

From reading up this possibly sounds like a recurring bug with Firebase.
Is there updates on Google's must recent fixes to this issue, the most recent I can find is 2017.

I have run my project on two separate devices (Amazon Kindle Fire HD and an Xperia S) and an emulator. Same error on all of them.

```
private void userLogin() 

    String email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

  mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(sign_in.this, task_list.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: Failed = " + task.getException().getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: which sdk version you are using for firebase auth ?

Comment: Hi Asad, I'm using SDK 28

Comment: try by implemeting 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'

Comment: Add your SHA1 fingerprint to the AUTH menu in Firebase or you Don't have google Play installed on Emulator/ Device

Comment: The old fire base auth version broke the build

Comment: My SHA1 fingerprint is already added to the AUTH menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was due to testing with an Amazon kindle fire HD. The kindle uses FireOS which doesn’t have Google play services hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check one of this.
1. SHA1 is provided to your app.
2. You must have the google-services.json on your root app.
3. configure your dependencies.
4. Make sure you enabled the Email/Password auth. In the firebase console authentication tab.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this on Build

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }
}
```

FYI. Nothing wrong in your code. Just the set up thing.

Please take time to do this.
[Do not skip, do not rush. You will loose more time than saving](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Hi Aizen, unfortunately all of the mentioned above are already there and were the first things I checked. The build still runs and doesn't crash, I can access the app via devices and emulator. I only get the mentioned error when attempting to sign in after providing email/password.

Comment: update answer. Make sure to enable Auth "Email and Password" Authentication.